# How to tell cmake to generate different default targets for out-of-source-builds?

Tags: cmake, out-of-source

How can I write a `CMakeLists.txt` file that accepts different out-of-source builds? I'm not talking about Debug and Release, but more about something like one build for remote testing one for local testing, etc.

For example: If I go into the `build_local` build directory and run `make` I want to have the sources compiled for local configration. If I run `make` in the `build_production` build directory I want to compile the sources using a different configuration. I understand that out of source builds are what I need. I just don't quite understand how to:

1. tell cmake what kind of configuration to generate (e.g., `cd build_local; cmake -D local`?)
2. how to write a `CMakeLists.txt` file in a way that it generates different **default** target (i.e. `make all` or `make`) depending on the configuration

Has someone an example or a link to appropriate documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a build directory for each configuration. But you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `if` command you can fill **default** target(and others) with different meanings, dependent of configuration.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
option(LOCAL "Build local-testing project" OFF)
if(LOCAL)
    add_executable(program_local local.c)
else()
    add_executable(program_remote remote.c)
endif()
```

*local* build:

```
cd build_local
cmake -DLOCAL=ON ..
make
...
```

*remote* build:

```
cd build_remote
cmake ..
make
```

In `if` branches you can use even different `add_subdirectory()` commands, so your *configured* project may completely differ for different configurations.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for One question remains though, how do I set the default target? Assuming I have a few custom targets (i.e. via `add_custom_target` or `add_custom_command`) and I want to make one of them the default for `make all` depending on the configuration? Thanks.

Comment: `add_custom_target(local_target ${LOCAL_TARGET_TYPE} ...)`. `LOCAL_TARGET_TYPE` should be set to `ALL` if you want it to be executed with `make all`. Otherwise it may be leaved undefined.